# VSC Snippets variable transformation using Regex quantifiers i.e. {1,3}

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

So, I wanna create a snippet that turns e.g. `rgba(102,83,47,1)` type strings into `102 83 47`.
I already wrote a working RegEx expression:
regexr.com/7mo33

```
(?:rgba\((\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3}),.*)
```

Which returns the RGB values into three capture groups.

But my VCS snippet doesn't seem to be working:

```
    "Vic3araxRGBpickertoPDX": {
        "prefix": [
            "RGB Picker to Clausewitz"
        ],
        "body": [
            "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/rgba\((\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3}),.*/$1 $2 $3/}"
        ],
        "description": "Removes the rgb() and turns commas into space"
    },
```

It's simply returning `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/rgba\((\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3}),.*/   /}`
My best guess is that the quantifier brackets at `\d{1,3}` mess with the variable transformer, but I have no idea.

Btw. I'm not married to that RegEx expression, so if there's a better way to do it, I wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `body` property to

```json
    "body": [
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/rgba\\((\\d{1,3}),(\\d{1,3}),(\\d{1,3}),.*\\)/$1 $2 $3/}"
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured there's something like the double `\\` needed to not accidentally escape, but none of what I found searching online explicitly told me about it (in terms I realized).